# How to remove duplicate values for specific key in multi-dimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following multi-dimentional array:

```
<?php 
$array = array(
array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1),
array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1),
array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1));
```

How can I remove the duplicate `first` values? While preserving the duplicate `second` values.

After processing the array should be:

```
array(
array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1));
```

See: http://codepad.org/tMh28KMf

Comment: Can you give us an example with keys that should be removed and some that should not? With the expected result of course!

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're looking for in the output.  Do you want `$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);` or `$array = array(array('first' => 1), array('first' => 2), array('first' => 3));`?

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$array = array(
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1)
);

$temp = array();
$new = array();

foreach($array as $value)
{
    if(!in_array($value['first'],$temp))
    {
        $temp[] = $value['first'];
        $new[] = $value;
    } 
}
```

Now `$new` contains the following:

```
array(
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1),
);
```

Comment: thanks, but how if i also keys "second" and "third" - in second and third i don't have remove duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some `foreach` loops and reassemble the array yourself.  Check out PHP's [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/array_unique) too.

Comment: how can i use this for my example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't really understand what you need.  Do you want to also filter out duplicates in the `'second'` keys too?  It also might help to know what purpose this code is for.  There may be a better way to architect it overall.

Comment: Okay, I see you're not wanting to remove duplicates from subsequent keys after `'first'`.  But... what if you have some `'first'` duplicates, but they differ in subsequent keys `'second'` or `'third'`?

Answer (score 0):

This removes the duplicate arrays:

`$array = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array)));`

The keys are still the same so you might need to fix them.

Comment: i would like remove values only from keys "first" - in my array can be moreover keys, for example "second" and "third" - for these keys can't not remove duplicate

Comment: This is a very "inelegant" method.

Answer (score 0):

what if the array is like this

```
$array = array(
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 12),
    array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1)
);

$temp = array();
$new = array();
```

You want new array $new contains the following:

```
array(
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1),
);
```

or

```
array(
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 1, 'second' => 12),
    array('first' => 2, 'second' => 1),
    array('first' => 3, 'second' => 1),
);
```

?